# Convert a list of digits to a number HASKELL

Tags: haskell, ghci, winghci

I want to make a function in haskell that given a list of single digits, i make the full number. I was thinking in using intensive lists and patrons, as the code it follows:

```
funcion5 (x:xs) = [y*(10^w) | y <- (x:xs) w]
```

The idea is, to go over the list and multiplie each digit to 10 pow to the position of the number. Finally i only have to sum all digits and I have the number as this:

```
sum (funcion5 (x:xs))
```

Can anyone help me, please? Thanks

Comment: [Horner's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) is useful.

Answer (score 2):

This may simply be done by folding with `foldl1 :: Foldable t => (a -> a -> a) -> t a -> a` as follows;

```
Prelude> foldl1 (\x y -> 10*x+y) [1,2,3]
123
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a "fold" pattern for this. We thus write this in terms of [**`foldl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldl):

```
function5 :: Num n => [n] -> n
function5 = foldl f 0
    where f a x = ...
```

So here `f` takes two parameters `a` (the thus far generated number), and `x` the next digit.

In a [positional notation system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation), one can obtain the value by "scanning" left-to-right and each time multiplying the thus far obtained value with the radix, and adding the next digit. So this is the logic you need to "encode" in `f`: taking the thus far obtained value, and the next digit, and producing the next value.

Answer (score 1):

```
multiplos_10 = [10^x | x <- [0..]]
aux (x:xs) = sum ([a*b | (a,b) <- zip (x:xs) multiplos_10])
a_numero (x:xs) = aux (reverse(x:xs))
```