# Convert a list of digits to a natural number

Tags: haskell

Given a a list of digits representing a natural number and a base >2, how can one output the proper natural number. i.e given [1,2,3] and base 10 we get 123. Given [1,0,1] and base 2 we get 5.

There are examples that cover converting numbers to lists using div and mod, but I don't know how to do the reverse (for binary numbers, for decimals its easy enough to convert a list of digits to int directly but I assume there is a mathematical approach that works in both cases).

```
--For decimal conversion:
fromDigits :: [Integer] -> Integer
fromDigits xs = aux xs 0
where aux [] acc = acc
      aux (x:xs) acc  = aux xs ((acc * 10) + x)
```

Comment: Well you basically already have the required logic, there is only one constant here that should be replaced with a variable.

Comment: You have written `fromDigits` for base 10 so just replace `fromDigits xs` with `fromDigits 10 xs` and change `10` to be a variable. Also update the type

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a list of digits to a number HASKELL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53140675/convert-a-list-of-digits-to-a-number-haskell)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A positional number system with radix *r* is structured in such way, such that a number *a<sub>1</sub>a<sub>2</sub>…a<sub>n</sub>* with *a<sub>i</sub>* a digit, has value:

[image: sum of a_i times r^(n-i)]

So that means we can obtain the number for a sequence of of digits through:

```
fromDigits :: (Num a, Foldable f) => a -> f a -> a
fromDigits r = foldl (\a x -> r * a + x) 0
```

or syntactically a bit more compact:

```
fromDigits :: (Num a, Foldable f) => a -> f a -> a
fromDigits r = foldl ((+) . (r *)) 0
```

Each iteration, we thus multiply the accumulator with the radix `r`, and then we add the next digit to it. Eventually a the first digit will thus by multiplied with the radix `r` *n* times if the number contains *n* digits.

For example the number `1425` has different values for different radices:

```
Prelude> fromDigits 6 [1,4,2,5]
377
Prelude> fromDigits 7 [1,4,2,5]
558
Prelude> fromDigits 8 [1,4,2,5]
789
Prelude> fromDigits 9 [1,4,2,5]
1076
Prelude> fromDigits 10 [1,4,2,5]
1425
```